# What is this plant with dark green ovate hairy leaves in my indoor pot?

Tags: identification, flowers, annuals

I'm trying to grow a indoor herbs garden. I have reused soil from flowering pots from another location. The herbs didn't grow at all (I think bad seeds), but in one of the pots this appeared.

[image]

Here is a closeup of one of the tips
[image]

And one of the stem at the base
[image]

Comment: Are the leaves kind of sticky?  I don't know what that is but I've had similar plants grow in my vegetable beds and they produced lots of small pink petunia-like flowers.  It was pretty for a weed so I left it to grow.

Comment: What was growing where the soil was at last year?

Comment: @llemay, kind of sticky, but not very much.

Comment: @blackthumb, I don't think there was anything in the soil 2 years, but it was in a balcony with a lot of indoor flowers (I don't know the kind). This plant is about one year old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a Petunia x hybrida. It Must have germinated from a petunia that went to seed in the mix earlier. If you give it daylight it should bloom, although it might not be the most attractive form.